# Elm Colon Equals Operator

Tags: elm, colon-equals

When attempting to decode larger json values, I've ran into the following code in the `Json-Decode-Extra` library. (located [here](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/circuithub/elm-json-extra/latest/Json-Decode-Extra))

```
import Date (Date)

type alias User =
  { id                : Int
  , createdAt         : Date
  , updatedAt         : Date
  , deletedAt         : Maybe Date
  , username          : Maybe String
  , email             : Maybe String
  , fullname          : Maybe String
  , avatar            : Maybe String
  , isModerator       : Bool
  , isOrganization    : Bool
  , isAdmin           : Bool
  }

metaDecoder : (Int -> Date -> Date -> Maybe Date -> b) -> Decoder b
metaDecoder f = f
  `map`      ("id"        := int)
  `apply` ("createdAt" := date)
  `apply` ("updatedAt" := date)
  `apply` ("deletedAt" := maybe date)

userDecoder : Decoder User
userDecoder = metaDecoder User
  `apply` ("username"          := maybe string)
  `apply` ("email"             := maybe string)
  `apply` ("fullname"          := maybe string)
  `apply` ("avatar"            := maybe string)
  `apply` ("isModerator"       := bool)
  `apply` ("isOrganization"    := bool)
  `apply` ("isAdmin"           := bool)
```

However, I'm constantly running into a compiler error for the `:=` operator. Where is this defined? The JSON decode tutorials don't explicitly import this operator anywhere.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In Elm 0.18, the `:=` operator was replaced by `Json.Decode.field`, and using backticks for infix operators was removed.

You are using a package (circuithub/elm-json-extra) which has not been updated to Elm 0.18.

Consider switching to use the package maintained by the Elm community: [`elm-community/json-extra`](http://package.elm-lang.org/packages/circuithub/elm-json-extra/2.2.1/Json-Decode-Extra). You can use `andMap` instead of `apply`. Here is your example code upgraded to the new library and Elm 0.18:

```elm
import Date exposing (Date)
import Json.Decode exposing (..)
import Json.Decode.Extra exposing (andMap, date)

metaDecoder : (Int -> Date -> Date -> Maybe Date -> b) -> Decoder b
metaDecoder f =
    succeed f
        |> andMap (field "id" int)
        |> andMap (field "createdAt" date)
        |> andMap (field "updatedAt" date)
        |> andMap (field "deletedAt" (maybe date))

userDecoder : Decoder User
userDecoder =
    metaDecoder User
        |> andMap (field "username" (maybe string))
        |> andMap (field "email" (maybe string))
        |> andMap (field "fullname" (maybe string))
        |> andMap (field "avatar" (maybe string))
        |> andMap (field "isModerator" bool)
        |> andMap (field "isOrganization" bool)
        |> andMap (field "isAdmin" bool)
```

Note that the `elm-community/json-extra` package also exports an infix operator `|:` which is an infix version of `andMap`. You could use this to make your code more concise. For example:

```elm
metaDecoder : (Int -> Date -> Date -> Maybe Date -> b) -> Decoder b
metaDecoder f =
    succeed f
        |: field "id" int
        |: field "createdAt" date
        |: field "updatedAt" date
        |: field "deletedAt" (maybe date)
```